# How to render a text item in my App using the fonts that are already installed on a users PC?

Tags: javascript, filesystemobject

I have a text "name" in my App that I want to be styled using the fonts that are installed on users PC (locally) which I would fetch using a function like filesystemobject. Something like this (This is only an indicative code to only get the filenames first.)

```
  <html>
  <head>

  <script>    

  function ShowFolderFileList()
  {
  var fso, f, f1, fc, s;
  fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  f = fso.GetFolder("My Folder");
  fc = new Enumerator(f.files);
  s = "";
  for (; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext())
  {
  s += fc.item();
  s += "<br>";
  }
  document.write(s);
  } 
  </script>


  </head>

  <body>   

  <form name="myForm">
  <input type="Button" value="Get File" onClick='ShowFolderFileList'>

  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I have tried and explained my question as much as possible. Do comment if require more details I shall provide more information pertaining to your query.

Comment: What do you mean by "the font in users PC". There is not one single font.

Comment: Google for "css font-family".

Comment: If you don't use a webfont, the browser will use a local font.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access the fonts embedded in users navigators, known as "web safe fonts". These classic fonts are supposed to be widely available, cross-OS. Full "web safe font" list is available via google :)

To use one of them, simply use a CSS rule, like : 
p {font-family: "Times New Roman";}

I'm sure you expect more specific fonts, and as far as I know, you can't list the font installed on the user PC via javascript. Flash might be needed for that. However, i found this piece of code that can say if a font is installed or not on the user computer, this may serve your objective.

```js
/**
 * JavaScript code to detect available availability of a
 * particular font in a browser using JavaScript and CSS.
 *
 * Author : Lalit Patel
 * Website: http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/
 * License: Apache Software License 2.0
 *          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * Version: 0.15 (21 Sep 2009)
 *          Changed comparision font to default from sans-default-default,
 *          as in FF3.0 font of child element didn't fallback
 *          to parent element if the font is missing.
 * Version: 0.2 (04 Mar 2012)
 *          Comparing font against all the 3 generic font families ie,
 *          'monospace', 'sans-serif' and 'sans'. If it doesn't match all 3
 *          then that font is 100% not available in the system
 * Version: 0.3 (24 Mar 2012)
 *          Replaced sans with serif in the list of baseFonts
 */

/**
 * Usage: d = new Detector();
 *        d.detect('font name');
 */
var Detector = function() {
    // a font will be compared against all the three default fonts.
    // and if it doesn't match all 3 then that font is not available.
    var baseFonts = ['monospace', 'sans-serif', 'serif'];

    //we use m or w because these two characters take up the maximum width.
    // And we use a LLi so that the same matching fonts can get separated
    var testString = "mmmmmmmmmmlli";

    //we test using 72px font size, we may use any size. I guess larger the better.
    var testSize = '72px';

    var h = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    // create a SPAN in the document to get the width of the text we use to test
    var s = document.createElement("span");
    s.style.fontSize = testSize;
    s.innerHTML = testString;
    var defaultWidth = {};
    var defaultHeight = {};
    for (var index in baseFonts) {
        //get the default width for the three base fonts
        s.style.fontFamily = baseFonts[index];
        h.appendChild(s);
        defaultWidth[baseFonts[index]] = s.offsetWidth; //width for the default font
        defaultHeight[baseFonts[index]] = s.offsetHeight; //height for the defualt font
        h.removeChild(s);
    }

    function detect(font) {
        var detected = false;
        for (var index in baseFonts) {
            s.style.fontFamily = font + ',' + baseFonts[index]; // name of the font along with the base font for fallback.
            h.appendChild(s);
            var matched = (s.offsetWidth != defaultWidth[baseFonts[index]] || s.offsetHeight != defaultHeight[baseFonts[index]]);
            h.removeChild(s);
            detected = detected || matched;
        }
        return detected;
    }

    this.detect = detect;
};
```